# PCLXL (PCL6) supports color fill patterns?

Tags: pcl, pcl6, pclxl

I need to implement color fill patterns in PCLXL (PCL6) (RastPattern). With black and white patterns I have not problems. With color I have issues ussing ColorMapping eDirectPixel and too using eIndexedPixel.

Somebody has an example or knowns how to implement color fill patterns in PCLXL?

I tried to create a Color RGB custom pallete with two colors (example, red and white) and it not works. I tried too to modify RasterBuffer to change the pattern for add color and it not works too.

Thanks.